# Switching ViewController

Tags: ios, view, switch-statement, viewcontroller

I'm having a trouble with my app on iOS. I´m trying to switch between some ViewControllers, but it doesn't work properly.

Right now I've got three ViewControllers the first one will be a splash image and in a specific time'll switch to a second ViewController, but in this moment the first View uses a button to perform this action. The second View'll be a login screen, but now it's a fake login with a button switching to the third ViewController which will perform some complex stuff.

My problem is in the process switching from the first to the second ViewController. If I use the IBAction attached to the button it works properly, but if I use a NSTimer or something like a performSelector/PerformSelectorOnMainThread it doesn't work properly (the app orientation changes and the button in the second ViewController doesn't work).

ViewController1.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    float timer=5.0;
    [self performSelector:@selector(startAfterInterval) withObject:nil afterDelay:timer];
}

- (void) startAfterInterval {
    LoginViewController * loginViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];

    [[[self view] window] addSubview:loginViewController.view];
}

- (IBAction)NextView:(id)sender {
    LoginViewController * loginViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];

    [[[self view] window] addSubview:loginViewController.view];
}
@end
```

Could anyone help me? thanks in advice.

Comment: Instead of presenting a new view controller make use of imageview that animates for 5 seconds and hides displaying your view for login.
this is a mere suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, and I got different results, but they were erratic. Sometimes, clicking the button in LoginViewController worked and other time it caused a crash. The reason for this, is that LoginViewController is being deallocated. You're adding its view to the window, but not the controller -- this is not the way it should be done. If you want to just change the controllers without using a navigation controller or a modal presentation, then you should change the root view controller of the window instead of adding a view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    float timer=5.0;
    [self performSelector:@selector(startAfterInterval) withObject:nil afterDelay:timer];
}

- (void) startAfterInterval {
    LoginViewController * loginViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
    self.view.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;
}

- (IBAction)NextView:(id)sender {
    LoginViewController * loginViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
     self.view.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;
}
```

Both methods will work fine if you do it this way.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks a lot. But I should investigate the modal way.